# is there a Curl -v argument in php?

Tags: php, curl

Is there any Curl function in PHP that is similar to the '-v' argument from the linux shell?
Because the '-v' argument gives me something like this:

```
$ curl -v https://www.bankinter.com
* About to connect() to www.bankinter.com port 443 (#0)
* Trying 195.235.25.185... connected
* Connected to www.bankinter.com (195.235.25.185) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    *//I NEED HERE...*
    * SSL connection using AES256-SHA
    * Server certificate:
    * subject: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=ES; 2.5.4.15=V1.0, Clause
    5.(b); serialNumber=A28157360; C=ES; ST=Madrid; L=Tres Cantos;
    O=Bankinter S.A.; OU=Bankinter S.A.; OU=Terms of use at 
    www.verisign.com/rpa (c)05; CN=www.bankinter.com
    * start date: 2009-12-07 00:00:00 GMT
    * expire date: 2011-01-06 23:59:59 GMT
    * common name: www.bankinter.com (matched)
    * issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network;
    OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06; CN=VeriSign
    Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
    * SSL certificate verify ok.
    * //...TO HERE*
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7
OpenSSL/0.9.8l zlib/1.2.3
> Host: www.bankinter.com
> Accept: */*
>
```

And I need to retrieve that same data to a txt file in PHP... 
Anybody knows any way?

Thanks, and sorry for the poor english

P.S. "www.bankinter.com" it's just a test

Comment: What's your specific goal here? To get information on the SSL certificate?

Comment: I think `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` and `CURLOPT_CERTINFO` is what you are looking for.  You'd config it with e.g. [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 1):

From the CURL documentation:

```
-v, --verbose       Make the operation more talkative
```

So with this in mind, you could add the CURL option VERBOSE and then save the output to a file. Try this:

**CURL option**

```
$outputFile = 'curlOutput.txt';

$handle=curl_init('https://www.bankinter.com');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_STDERR,$f = fopen($outputFile, "w+"));
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
curl_exec($handle);

fclose($f);
```

**CURL alternative**

```
$g = stream_context_create (array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => true)));
$r = stream_socket_client("ssl://www.google.com:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $g);
$cont = stream_context_get_params($r);
print_r( openssl_x509_parse($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate"]) );
```

**UPDATED** to include CURLOPT_CERTINFO (credit [Crayon Violent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184595/crayon-violent))

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that

Comment: It worked on saving to the file, I've managed that, but the data i'm retrieving is not what I need. I need the data regarding SSL certificate.

Comment: This data is viewable on my enviroment, what version of the php-curl library are you running? I would suggest updateing to the latest version if possible.

Comment: I'm Running 7.36.0, that's the latest my SO supports (php 5.4.31)

Comment: I've update the answer with a CURL alternative, does that provide you with the information you need?

Comment: @ErickGarciaTerra I think you probably want to throw `CURLOPT_CERTINFO` into the mix above

Comment: Thanks @crayon-violent update answer to include CURLOPT_CERTINFO

Comment: Any luck with this Erick?